# Python: Parsing in a nested list of numbers through command prompt

Tags: python, list, recursion, nested, numbers

I'm trying to write a python program (rec_list_sum.py) that finds the sum of a nested list of numbers recursively.

My input into Powershell terminal:

```
python rec_list_sum.py [1,2,3,[4,5],[6,7],8]
```

And my function takes in an array as such:

```
import sys

def recursive_list_sum(array):

    total = 0

    for ele in array:
        if isinstance(ele, list):
            total = total + recursive_list_sum(ele)
        else:
            total = total + ele

    return total
```

This is the part I have the problem with, parsing the input in:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    string = sys.argv[1]
    digits = [int(i) for i in str(string)]
    ans = recursive_list_sum(digits)

    print(ans)
```

I've got my code to work on a jupyter notebook but I simply can't seem to parse this input into python using PowerShell. Can anyone explain how?

Comment: Trust me I've scoured through existing posts on this website but none of them deal with parsing in a nested list of digits.

Comment: If you're the only one that is going to use it you could use eval. `digits = eval(string)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ast.literal_eval` to parse the input string as a Python expression:

```
from ast import literal_eval
ans = recursive_list_sum(literal_eval(sys.argv[1]))
```

Comment: That worked, thank you! Is there any other way of doing this other than importing ast ?

Comment: Glad to be of help. You can refer to my other answer for an example of how you can parse the input yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You can write a parser like this:

```
def parse(s):
    def _parse(s):
        output = []
        index = 0
        num = ''
        while index < len(s):
            char = s[index]
            index += 1
            if char.isdigit():
                num += char
            if char in ',]' and num:
                output.append(int(num))
                num = ''
            if char == '[':
                sublist, offset = _parse(s[index:])
                output.append(sublist)
                index += offset
            elif char == ']':
                break
        return output, index
    return _parse(s)[0][0]
```

so that:

```
parse('[1,2,3,[4,5],[6,7],8]')
```

returns:

```
[1, 2, 3, [4, 5], [6, 7], 8]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the json library with method loads()

```
import json
ans = json.loads(sys.argv[1])
```

ans will be then a list type that you can iterate normally

```
 >>> type(json.loads(ans))
 <class 'list'>
```